# Vectors and matrix as differential varaiables

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a function of matrix and vectors. I want to know how to calculate the derivative of this function with respect to the vectors.
 For examples: $a$ is a $2\times1$ vector. $M$ is a $2\times2$ matrix. The function reads $f=Ma$. Then how to calculate

1. $df/da$;
2. $df/dM$ ?

Comment: the derivative is the best linear approximation to the change in the function at the point. Whatever your concept of differentiation is, it ought to reflect this principle. To be more precise, the derivatives you ask for involve certain ad-hoc choices from my perspective. I could show you how to calculate them, but, it might not agree with what you're working from or on (is this just your question, or is it part of a larger study)

Comment: I'm not enthusiastic about such abuses of notation.  There is a well-defined notion of differentiating a function of several variables with respect to one of the variables when this variable is allowed to vary independently of the others.  This is called a partial derivative.  When you attempt to sweep the issue of how each individual component of $a$ or $M$ varies independently or in correlation with other components "under the carpet", you are begging for misunderstanding and mistaken manipulations.

Comment: Thanks@James S.Cook.@hardmath. This is just my question. I am working on a quantum physics problem and it involves calculation like this.

Comment: Maybe i can write the components of the vectors explicitly and take derivatives of these components instead, at last combine them back to vector form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the comments that $df/da$ is not awfully nice notation, I do not think that there are choices needed or one could call it "abuse of notation". I would would the question as follows: Take the vector spaces $M_2(\mathbb R)\cong\mathbb R^4$ and $\mathbb R^2$ and consider the function $f:M_2(\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $f(M,a):=Ma$. As a smooth function between finite dimensional vector spaces, this has a well defined derivative $Df:(M_2(\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R^2)\times(M_2(\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R^2)\to\mathbb R^2$, which is linear in the second variable. By restricting the second variable to one of the two factors, one obtains "partial derivatives" $D_1f:(M_2(\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R^2)\times M_2(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R^2$ and $D_1f:(M_2(\mathbb R)\times\mathbb R^2)\times \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, and it is quite reasonable to denote them by $\partial f/\partial M$ and $\partial f/\partial a$, respectively.

The actual computation is very easy, since the action of matrices on vectors is a bilinear map. The derivative can be computed by as a directional derivative, i.e. $Df(M,a)(N,b)$ can be computed as the derivative at $t=0$ of the curve $f(M+tN,a+tb)=Ma+t(Mb+Na)+t^2Nb$, so $Df(M,a)(N,b)=Mb+Na$ or $D_1f(M,a)$ is the map $N\mapsto Na$ whereas $D_2f(M,a)$ is the map $b\mapsto Mb$. In sloppy notation you would say that $\partial f/\partial a=M$ (which is more reasonable) and $\partial f/\partial M=a$, where you have to understand that $a$ is viewed as a linear map from $M_2(\mathbb R)$ to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: thanks!  the result you get is right. I have to check your description in detail afterwards.

Comment: According to the problem i am working on, f's derivative of a matrix should also be a matrix. and f's  derivative of a vector should also be a vector. It may still need to take the derivative of each component in my case

Comment: Your answer is logically right but i will need to find another one to fit my case

Comment: I am afraid that things won't change if you compute in components. Rather than that, you should probably check what you really mean by $df/da$ and $df/dM$.

Comment: This answer seems reasonable to me, but, beware when the matrix appears non-linearly it's not so simple... I suspect Andreas is well-aware of this. Furthermore, I suspect there are cannonical understandings of such derivatives known to matrix-theorists, there is something called the "vec" operator and it seems to me it gives the sort of math one needs to forge a purely computational theory of matrix or vector derivatives (but, this is speculation on my part, I haven't fleshed it out). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics) or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Comment: Thanks for the links and comment. I will check them later